# How to skip corrupt XML files and process only valid ones using SSIS package?

Tags: ssis, xml-parsing, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to parse few XML files through an SSIS package.The XML files are generated based on a daily schedule but some of the XML files are corrupt. I would like to know how to skip the corrupt files and process the remaining valid XML files.

Answer (score 0):

To skip the corrupted files would mean you know which are corrupted in advance. I'm pretty sure thats not your context, and what you would like is to that your SSIS package does not crash when parsing those files. You can set the **MaximumErrorCount** higher so your SSIS package will continue to execute even when it fails on those corrupted files.